# Firefox / Safari not storing any offline cache data

Tags: ios, firefox, safari, offline-caching, offlineapps

Given the following appcache-manifest :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#offline.manifest
#version 1.0 3-18-20141
CACHE:
offline.php
NETWORK:
*
FALLBACK:
* offline.php
```

And two simple php-files :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" manifest="offline.manifest">
<body>Offline, ohooohoo!
</body>
</html>
```

and:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" manifest="offline.manifest">
<body>Online, sucks!
</body>
</html>
```

I neither can get Firefox, nor Safari on IOS to work offline correctly. The manifest-file is delivered with the correct MIME-Types:

```
  AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
  AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

I'm quite amused that Firefox nor Safari is working, but Chrome. Using the about:cache?device=offline Option in Firefox, i get the following respoonse :

```
http://localhost/HTML5_SDK/offline.php  0 bytes     8   2014-03-18 17:34:49     2014-03-18 17:34:49
```

Which frankly means that a) my file is size zero and b) is expired as delivered.
I am freaking around with that stuff the whole day, and already did many nasty things as complety reinstalling the browser, killing mit Iphone with a brand new iOs and so on.

Chrome tells me that the offline.php is stored as FALLBACK EXLIPCIT with 465b, which matches.

Did anybody already manage to really get an offline-manifest with fallback working crossplattform-wide?

thanks for your adviced and best regards

Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use a wildcard in the Fallback section. This must be a URL pattern and might be enough to ruin the day for your browser.

You can achieve the same thing by specifying root.

```
FALLBACK:
/ offline.php
```

Lastly, if one of those php pages is `offline.php` then this does not need to be added to your `CACHE:` section because you have explicitly requested it in the html tag. From my experience it shouldnt hurt though.

Answer (score 0):

I've found exactly the same thing as this. And discovered that Firefox is really picky about the HTTP headers that the webserver sends back.

I was setting back a Cache-Control: no-store header (on the Manifest), which Chrome happily accepted, but Firefox errored silently with showing the 0 bytes stored that you reported.

This one change got it all working for me.